# Using One grid as grouped grid and as normal grid in ExtJs 4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-grid

In my application, I am using two ExtJs grid. One contains department ID's and when any row is selected in the first grid, the second grid is populated with department details based on selection in the first grid. I am using two normal ExtJS grid and every thing is working fine.

Now for one of the department (Department 10), I want to show [grouped grid](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/grid/groupgrid.html) in the second grid.

My question is, is it possible to use same grid for grouping as well as normal grid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Brown, you can try this code if you are grouping the records locally:

```
    store.clearGrouping(); //for normal grid and
    store.group(groupers, [direction]);   //for grouping grid
```

Not sure if it would work if you are using remoteGroup config option. Hope it helps.